# SQL + Ion Auth + CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT (
(SELECT SUM(vote_score)
FROM question_votes 
JOIN questions
ON vote_question = q_id
JOIN users
ON q_author = users.id
WHERE q_author` = users.id) 
+ 
(SELECT SUM(vote_score)
FROM answer_votes 
JOIN answers 
ON vote_answer = a_id
JOIN users
ON a_author = users.id
WHERE a_author = users.id)) AS rep
```

and I want it to be added here (Ion Auth's method):

```
    $this->db->select(
            array(
                $this->tables['users'].'.*',
                $this->tables['groups'].'.name AS '. $this->db->protect_identifiers('group'),
                $this->tables['groups'].'.description AS '. $this->db->protect_identifiers('group_description'),
                "(SELECT COUNT(`a_author`) FROM `answers` WHERE a_author = users.id) + (SELECT COUNT(`q_author`) FROM `questions` WHERE q_author = users.id )  AS total_posts",
                "SELECT 
((SELECT SUM(vote_score)
FROM question_votes 
JOIN questions
ON vote_question = q_id
JOIN users
ON q_author = users.id
WHERE q_author` = users.id) 
+ 
(SELECT SUM(vote_score)
FROM answer_votes 
JOIN answers 
ON vote_answer = a_id
JOIN users
ON a_author = users.id
WHERE a_author = users.id)) AS rep"
            )
        );
```

but I get the followin error:
[image: my error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the error message?

You have a (`) where shouldn't be any.

Change this: WHERE q_author' = users.id for this: `WHERE q_author = users.id`

Comment: Yeah, few seconds after posting the question, I found the mistake:
`(SELECT 
(SELECT SUM(vote_score)
FROM question_votes 
JOIN questions
ON vote_question = q_id
JOIN users
ON q_author = users.id
WHERE q_author = users.id) 
+ 
(SELECT SUM(vote_score)
FROM answer_votes 
JOIN answers 
ON vote_answer = a_id
JOIN users
ON a_author = users.id
WHERE a_author = users.id)) AS rep`

Comment: sometimes our heads get so tired that the obvious pass by..happens with everybody =)